# Convert T-SQL to LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql

I have the following query that I would like to convert to LINQ to SQL (c#) but am getting stuck.

```
select title, barcode, count (*) as pop_rank
from favourites
group by barcode, title
order by pop_rank desc
```

I got as far as

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();

using (db)
{
var test = from t in db.favourites
           group t by new 
           {
              t.barcode,
              t.title
           };
}
```

I'm struggling with adding the count and order by functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();

using (db)
{
 var test = 
          ( 
           from t in db.favourites
           group t by new 
           {
              t.barcode,
              t.title
            } into g 
             select new {g.Key.barcode, g.Key.title, pop_rank=g.Count()}
            ).OrderBy(a => a.pop_rank);
}
```

Comment: Intellisense is throwing up errors after the group by statement. The select statement is not recognised.